# Keep straight and sharp lines when sculpting with Dyntopo

Tags: mesh, sculpting, dynamic-topology

How do I keep a sharp and straight line when sculpting?If I decrease the res detail the line isn't sharp anymore and if I increase the res it becomes jiggly...and how do i keep the tip sharp?Thanks 
[image][image]

Comment: I don't think you can choose which line to sculpt with only if changing dyntopo detail. Choose another brush, Crease on Subtract mode if you want to sharpen and move it out or Pinch if only to sharpen

Answer (score 2):

Change the Dyntopo *Detail Refine Method* settings from *Subdivide Collapse* to *Subdivide Edges*.

[image]

Comment: Note that this will make dyntopo only subdividing geometry which will cause added details become much smoother. So this works at cost of amount of added geometry.